# InterpolatingFunction gives different result when plot

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I solve a series of ODE equations by `NDSolve`(`{t,0,200}` is the region), it gives results in the form of `InterpolatingFunction[sth][t]`. When I try to plot the function in follow way, it gives different picture.

```
Plot[InterpolatingFunction[sth][t], {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.0001}, {10^-7, -10^-7}}, PlotLabel -> "{t, 0, 200}"]
Plot[InterpolatingFunction[sth][t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.0001}, {10^-7, -10^-7}}, PlotLabel -> "{t, 0, 1}"]
```

there is not any error when I plot.

[image]
[image]

I wonder why this happened. I don't know how to add my `InterpolatingFunction[sth][t]` to the question, and my `NDSolve` is very complex, so I don't show.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your problem is. Because of your PlotRange function, you are only plotting between 0 and 0.0001, so the rest of the solution to the ODE (between 0 and 200) is not displayed.

Comment: @bills In my opinion, the `InterpolatingFunction` has all information of the equation, why the plot picture changes  when the "real plotrange" changes, I mean the function `PlotRange` changes only the range of axis and have no influence of `Plot`.

Comment: I think maybe it caused by the different of `PlotPints` and `MaxRecursion`, I try to change these two option but have no idea how to get the same picture.

Comment: Try `sth["Domain"]` to get the time range of the solution. Outside this range Plot extrapolates the function. And the plot-function creates starting values in the given time range!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don't know exactly what you mean `sth["Domain"]`. Since the `InterpolatingFunction` is given by the `NDSolve` which's domain is set as `{t,0,200}`, I think the domain of the `InterpolatingFunction` should also be `{t,0,200}`. Besides when I `Plot`, there is no error shows about "extrapolates".

Comment: @ 袁子奕 NDSolve domain, for example {t,0,200},  is set before evaluation . Excecuting NDSolve it might happen that the simulation is terminated because of numerical reasons. `sth["Domain"]` helps you to get the used simulation time range which might be considerably smaller than `{t,0,200}`!

Comment: Can't you provide a minimal `sth` so that we can observe the behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the reason behind the discrepancy is that when `Plot` decides at which points the target expression is to be evaluated, it assumes that the "typical scale" of the independent variable is of the same order as the range specified as the second argument of `Plot`. `PlotRange` doesn't matter here, it simply determines what area to include in the picture. So, when you ask to plot an expression in the range `{t, 0, 200}`, `Plot` doesn't try to be precise at a scale of `0.0001`. Neither does it try to be precise at such scale, when you ask it to plot the expression at the `{t, 0, 1}` range. So, basically, I would suggest that both pictures are nothing but numerical rubbish.

Consider the following to examples:

```
Last[Reap[
   Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0., 200.}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, Sin[t]}],
   PlotRange -> {{0., 0.0001}, {-1., 1.}}
]]][[1, 1 ;; 10]]
({{4.08163*10^-6,4.08163*10^-6},{3.92573,-0.706216},{8.18167,0.946788},{12.1556,-0.399337},{16.0515,-0.336847},{20.2777,0.989842},{24.2218,-0.790066},{28.4962,-0.220016},{32.6926,0.957044},{36.6069,-0.887643}}*)

Last[Reap[
   Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0., 1.}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, Sin[t]}],
   PlotRange -> {{0., 0.0001}, {-1., 1.}}
]]][[1, 1 ;; 10]]
(*{{2.04082*10^-8,2.04082*10^-8},{0.0196287,0.0196274},{0.0409084,0.0408969},{0.0607779,0.0607405},{0.0802576,0.0801715},{0.101388,0.101215},{0.121109,0.120813},{0.142481,0.141999},{0.163463,0.162736},{0.183035,0.182014}}*)
```

They show that when `Plot` is asked to plot an expression at a smaller scale, it uses a different grid to plot the expression than when it was asked to plot this expression at a larger scale, but still this grid is too dense for your `PlotRange`.

**P.S.**

If you want to examine your solution at such a small time scale relative to overall time of evolution, you should ensure that the time step that was used by `NDSolve` is appropriately small.

**EDIT**

Regarding your comment about making the pictures normal. That is how `Plot` builds the pictures:

1. First, it chooses the initial grid for the plot. The number of nodes in this grid is determined by internal `Plot` algorithms but will not be less that `PlotPoints` option value. `Plot` will add extra nodes if its internal algorithms return less nodes than specified in `PlotPoints` option value. What is important here is that `Plot` algorithms determine the number of grid nodes using your target expression and the second argument of `Plot`. `PlotRange` doesn't matter, in fact, this options is inherited form `Graphics`.
2. Then `Plot` examines how fast the target expression changes from node to node. If this change is sufficiently large, `Plot` will add extra nodes where necessary, but only if `MaxRecursion` is greater than zero and it will do extra sampling not more times than `MaxRecursion`. What is important here is that `Plot` decides whether it needs extra grid points using your target expression and the previous grid.

So, conclusions:

1. If you set `PlotRange` much smaller then the range specified as the second argument, then `MaxRecursion` is unlikely to help because internal `Plot` algorithms might just decide that you *don't need* to see details at such scale. `MaxRecusrion -> n` says to `Plot`: "You can do extra sampling up to n times *if you want*". But maybe in combination with `PlotPoints`, when the initial grid is already very detailed, it will work.

An example:

```
 Last[Reap[
   Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0., 1.}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, Sin[t]}], 
   PlotRange -> {{0., 0.0001}, {-1., 1.}}, MaxRecursion -> 1]]][[1, 1 ;; 10]] === 
 Last[Reap[
   Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0., 1.}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, Sin[t]}], 
   PlotRange -> {{0., 0.0001}, {-1., 1.}}, MaxRecursion -> 15]]][[1,
 1 ;; 10]]
 (*True*)
```

2. Setting `PlotPoints` to some appropriately large number *will* force `Plot` to use a very detailed grid, but note that `Plot` will use this detailed grid *everywhere*, not only inside the `PlotRange`.

An example:

```
Last[Reap[
  Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0., 1.}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, Sin[t]}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0., 0.0001}, {-1., 1.}}, PlotPoints -> 10^5]]][[1, 
1 ;; 10]]
(*{{1.00001*10^-11,1.00001*10^-11},{9.61814*10^-6,9.61814*10^-6},{0.0000200453,0.0000200453},{0.0000297815,0.0000297815},{0.0000393266,0.0000393266},{0.0000496808,0.0000496808},{0.0000593441,0.0000593441},{0.0000698163,0.0000698163},{0.0000800976,0.0000800976},{0.0000896878,0.0000896878}}}*)
```

Honestly, why not to just specify the second argument to `Plot` appropriately? :)

Comment: Yes, it shows why they have different picture, for "P.S.", I'm sure my `NDSolve` is appropriately small:). I look at the help manual and find that `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` will have influence on grid, so do you have any idea of how to change theses two options to make the picture same?

Comment: I have added an edit to address your comment.

Comment: BTW, because `InterpolatingFunction` seems to be only indirectly connected to the issue, maybe it is worth changing the title of the question to something that points more to `Plot` than to `InterpolatingFunction`.